# Dynamic Run-Time object creation: Keep intellisense?

Tags: c#, dynamic, intellisense

Recently I have been exploring using the fancy new dynamic keyword introduced in C# 4.0 (DynamicObject, ExpandoObject etc..)

Now I can identify several uses (and several pitfalls) for the new introduction, but for the purpose of my project, and for this question - I am looking into cleaning up my late-bound string-based indexed collections to make them more safe.

So, before dynamics I had:

```
Car car1 = CARWarehouse1["Honda"];
```

And WITH dynamics I can now do (where CARWarehouse1 now extends the DynamicObjects base)

```
Car car1 = CARWarehouse1.Honda
```

This is all well and good, and from a quick glance it looks like I have achieved what I wanted.. but have I?
Because lets face it, for either method at compile time should I have mistyped my referenced car type, the compiler won't have a problem, but I will run into issues at runtime.

Therefore, what I really need is compile time property checking, and Intellisense support. So - can I do it?

I know that there are libraries out there such as Moq that have this capability, and Resharper gives some sort of support within intellisense, but I'm looking for a more rounded solution.

Any ideas, big, small, easy or complex are welcome.

Comment: Does your CARWarehouse1 (odd capitalization btw) *know* at compile-time that it has a `Honda` but not a `Honder`? If not, how can the compiler complain? If so, why aren't you using static typing?

Comment: Yeah the project doesn't actually use CARWarehouse1, its just an example, the Cars would be being added to the CarWarehouse at runtime via a database or xml or whatever, and i don't want the cars to be strongly typed. I see what your saying, but i was hoping that there would be some way for the intellisense to actually run the method and return the dynamic properties. I'd be happy to look into going down the code-generation route, as in with linq entities. I just want to know what is possible

Comment: Which database would it look in? Your production one? Test? Something else? Do you *really* want a database call while you're compiling? What about if you're not on a network with a database... think about all the things that could go wrong here...

Comment: F# 3.0 type providers can do something like this. But I don't think something like that exists in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, no such thing for dynamic types.

Basically the compiler just skips all checks on variables marked as `dynamic` because there is no way to check anything. Properties on dynamic objects may be created at runtime, so the code can't be checked at compile time for accuracy.

Comment: Sad but true, they should think about supporting something like annotations on comments to tell intellisense.... PHP does a similar thing...

Answer (score 1):

If compile time checks and intellisense are important, don't use `dynamic`.  If the scope of the object is pretty small you could use anonymous types instead, but I don't get the impression that's applicable to your situation.  I'd suggest you just define the types you need, and stick with dictionaries and hashtables for any properties that you can't predict when coding.